# How to track down a crash in graphics drivers

Tags: opengl, nvidia

I have a program that uses OpenGL for drawing texture images and rendering them on a 3d model.  All works well until I set the maximum texture size to 16384, then I get a crash.  I have debug tracing in my code, and it shows the crash happening at a different location each time, and the debugger reports the crash in nvoglv32.dll, location 0x6a24e899.  Exception code is 0xC0000406, which is a stack overflow.  This is inside the graphics drivers, not in my code, so I'm trying to figure out what I can do to detect and prevent this crash.

It is also intermittent.  I can run the same code several times, and it will run OK the first 10, and then crash.

I realise that 16K textures are quite large, and I'm using several of them, so the memory usage is quite high - probably around 1Gb for the textures alone, but I've got error checking on all the allocations, and also calling glGetError() at lots of point through my rendering code, and everything looks like it's OK.  If the creation of the large textures fails, my code automatically downscales the images until they succeed.

What else can I do to figure out the cause, detect the error and prevent crashing?

Comment: sound like out of memory for texture2D maps

Comment: Use a debug context and enable a debug callback. Also, try to record the crash with `apitrace` and see if the replay also crashes randomly. One can easily trigger crashes in the driver by undefined behavior on the client side, especially with invalid pointers of any kind. There is always the possibility of having hit a driver bug, but I wouldn't jump to conclusions early on.

Comment: what is the device you work with?

Comment: @Proxytype - I'm using NVidia GTX750 with 2Gb of graphics mem, but customers (perhaps 5%) are having issues on a range of other devices.  I've checked with GPU-Z, and the graphics memory usage peaks at high amounts (around 1.5Gb), but not at the limit.

Comment: @derhass - Thanks for the tip on debug context.  I've not used this before.  I'll see what I get from the debug callback.

Comment: @derhass - I have set up the debug context, and it does not report any errors.  I guess as it is a crash in the drivers, the driver can't report it.  It's not an error in parameters given to the driver, but a stack overflow error within.